# using malloc with realloc together to allocate when buffer length is over

Tags: c

I'm trying to allocate a buffer of charachters, then try to reallocate it if the buffer size is too large. here is my way, I need to check if the logic is correct or not.

```
char *buffer = malloc(10*sizeof(char));

if(buffer_length_is_over)
  {
    char *tmp;
    tmp = realloc(buffer , 11 * sizeof *buffer );
    if (!tmp)
      {
        // could not resize data; handle as appropriate
      }
    else
      {
        buffer = tmp;
        // process extended buffer
      } 
  }
```

Comment: sorry it was a mistake that I typed

Comment: @amdixon how to get the size of buffer ? is it sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0])

Comment: No, you can't use `sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0])` - that only works for array variables. But you already know the size of the buffer because you allocated it - what is the problem ?

Comment: you need to manage the size yourself - which is what buffer_length_is_over is presumably related to

Comment: Buffer is a pointer and not an array. `sizeof` is not the right tool here.

Comment: so the size of the buffer is 10*sizeof(char) ?

Comment: Don't need to, because `realloc()` with `NULL` as first parameter is equivalent to `malloc()`. What you do need to do is check for `NULL` after `malloc()`/`realloc()`.

Comment: The program only **needs to remember** the current number of elements. If it needs more, it needs to reallocate (and remember the new count (or size))

Comment: @Paul R if I free buffer, is temp is freed also ? or should I free both

Comment: @andre: when you realloc there is still only one buffer - it's just a different size now - you just `free(buffer);` either way.

Comment: @andre for each malloc/realloc/calloc you should call free exactly once.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if `tmp = realloc(buffer, newsize)` returns `NULL`, then `buffer` is still a valid pointer to the old buffer contents at the previous size, so you might need to free it as part of your error recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template code (`SomeType` can be anything, `13` could be anything, too ;-)

```
SomeType get_one(FILE *fp);

void somefunc(void)
{
SomeType *buff=NULL;
int done=0;
size_t size, idx;

size=idx=0;
while( !done ) {
    if (idx >= size) {
            SomeType *tmp;
            tmp = realloc(buff, (size+13) * sizeof *tmp);
            if (!tmp) { /*
                    ... handle error here.
                    ... buff is still valid,
                    ... and contains the original contents
                    ... */ }
            else { buff=tmp; size += 13; }
            }
    buff[idx++] = get_one(stdin);
    /* maybe set `done` here, or break out of the loop */
    }

/* do usefull stuff with buff */

free(buff);
}
```